# difficulty when using contravariant type parameters for both a type parameter and return type of a method

Tags: scala, generics, contravariance

I am attempting to build a behaviour tree library in scala but I am having trouble with the variance. The following is a simplified version of a Node:

```
sealed trait State[+O]
case class Running[+O](curOut: O, node: Node[O,_]) extends State[O]
case class Success[+O](out: O) extends State[O]
case object Failure extends State[Nothing]

trait Node[-I,C] {
    protected def canRun(item: I, context: C, tick: Int): Boolean
    protected def run[O <: I](item: I, context: C, tick: Int): State[O]

    def apply[O <: I](item: I, context: C, tick: Int): State[O] = {
        if (canRun(item, context, tick)) run(item, context, tick)
        else Failure
    }
}
```

whenever I try to instantiate `Node` however, it complains that `method run overrides nothing`:

```
val node = new Node[Int,Any] {

    override protected def run(item: Int, context: Any, tick: Int): State[Int] = ???

    override protected def canRun(item: Int, context: Any, tick: Int): Boolean = ???
}
```

I have tried changing `O` in `Node` to a type member but that complains that `Covariant I is used in contravariant position`:

```
type O <: I
```

What I am trying to ask is how can I use a contravariant type parameter as the type for a method parameter and for a method return type? Ideally  I would not like to have to make `I` contravariant for reusability purposes in parent and decorator nodes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question

> how can I use a contravariant type parameter as the type for a method parameter and for a method return type?

You can't, a conta- (or co)-variant type parameter cannot be used in both a method parameter and the return type.

My recommendation to work around this is to either remove the `node` parameter from the `Running` case class. Or to replace the parameter with a read-only trait. For example:

```
case class Running[+O](curOut: O, process: Process[O]) extends State[O]
trait Process[+O] {
  def currentState: State[O]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> it complains that method run overrides nothing

That's because overriding method must have the same type parameters, you just replace `I` and `C`, so in this case it must be

```
new Node[Int,Any] {

    override protected def run[O <: Int](item: Int, context: Any, tick: Int): State[O] = ???

    override protected def canRun(item: Int, context: Any, tick: Int): Boolean = ???
}
```

Note that you this signature says "caller can get `State[O]` for any `O <: Int` it wants", e.g. `Nothing`. You can't really meaningfully implement a method with this signature.

If you want to get this signature for `run`, then in `Node` it probably should be

```
protected def run(item: I, context: C, tick: Int): State[I]
```

which means `I` can't be contravariant (or covariant, for that matter).